# Ubuntu server 14.04.5 LTS static ip no internet

Tags: networking, static-ip

I am new to Ubuntu.
I made a new installation of Ubuntu, and [set up a static IP](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-ubuntu-server-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address/).

But a ping on a gateway responds with `destination Host Unreachable.`
I connected my Ethernet wire to other PC (Windows 10) and set up static IP and all is working good.

On the Ubuntu PC, I had previously installed Lubuntu and same static IP setup did work, so I don't know where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Could you post a copy of your interfaces file? located in /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: <blink>
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 84.237.228.XX
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 84.237.228.0
broadcast 84.237.228.255
gateway 84.237.228.1
dns-nameservers 195.122.12.242 80.232.230.242
</blink>

Comment: Is that your external IP? Bcause you cannot set your ip to your external IP. You have to use your internal ip it looks somthing like this (most of the time): 192.168.0.123

Comment: i have static ip from ISP

Comment: you should check your firewall and be sure there is nothing in rules block the traffic

Comment: the same ethernet wire is working on other 2pc whit (win 10 and win xp) installed and static ip setup.

Comment: Sometimes adding the gateway to list of dns-nameservers helps: dns-nameservers 84.237.228.1  Also, some ISPs require to register the MAC address of eth0 with them or DNS requests are ignored.

Comment: dns-nameservers 84.237.228.1 not helping.
just took router(another) and using same ethernet wire connected in WAN port+static ip setup and it has internet, this only confirm that its something about ubuntu

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed pci ethernet card and reinstall and all is working.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a external IP what i suggest you do is remove everything again and change yoru file to this:

`auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp`

After that save it connect to the internet again and type in the console:

`ifconfig` and copy that into a comment here

Comment: dhcp is not working, because my internet provider setup for me static ip,
i cant copy and post from console, because i have no internet on that pc!